# $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin {xt}}{1+t} \ dt $ Lebesgue Integral

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

could you please help me.
And let me notice how bad I am please.

> Problem: Calculate the derivative $F^\prime(x)$ of the function $F$ defined by the Lebesgue integral

$$F(X) = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\sin {xt}}{1+t} \ dt , x\in [0,1]$$

My attempt:

Since the function $\dfrac{\sin {xt}}{1 + t}$ is a bounded function on $[0, 1]$, then the integral (Riemann usual) $\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\sin {xt}}{1+t} \ dt $converges, which implies that the integral of Lebesgue $\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\sin {xt}}{1 + t} \ dt $ exists, so $f$ is summable.

Then using Theorem 9.6 which tells us that whatever the summable function $f$ in the segment $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, in almost all points the equality

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \ dt = f(x)$$

Then the $F^\prime (x)$ is equal to.

$$F^\prime(x) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin {xt}}{1+t} \ dt = \dfrac{\sin {x(1)}}{1+(1)} = \dfrac{\sin {x}}{2}$$

Many thanks

Comment: Seems good for me - but I'm not an expert in higher analysis. However, it would be nice if you could at the source where your "Theorem 9.6" is written, or is this in one of your lecture notes?

Comment: @LegNaiB Yes, it's in my notes.
And it is this: -Theorem 9.6. Whatever the summable function f in a segment [a, b] ⊂ R, in almost all points they are equal.
And thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @LegNaiB No, its wrong. The theorem is for functions $f$ that do not depend on $x$, and then the $x$ is in the integral limits. Neither hold in this case. Furthermore, $F(x)$ is an odd function; hence $F'$ must be an **even** function, which $(\sin x)/2$ is not

Comment: Ah good to know. I didn't know either that the function $f$ is not allowed to depend on $x$. That's why I asked where this theorem came from. If this theorem would be true (where $f$ can depend on $x$) his conclusions would be correct

Comment: @LegNaiB relevant terms to google regarding this: differentiation under the integral sign, leibniz integral rule, integral with parameter, Feynman trick, multivariate chain rule

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I will have a look into that :)

Answer (score 1):

No, its wrong. The theorem you quote is for functions $f$ that do not depend on $x$, and then the $x$ is in the integral limits. Neither hold in this case. Furthermore, $F(x)$ is an odd function; hence $F'$ must be an **even** function, which $(\sin x)/2$ is not.

You should check with appropriate limit theorems that you are allowed to differentiate under the integral sign, giving
$$ F'(x) = \int_0^1   \frac{\cos(xt)tdt}{1+t}.$$
I don't know what sort of answer  you're looking for, but [Wolfram tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+cos%28xt%29t%2F%281%2Bt%29+dt+from+t%3D0+to+1) that there is an expression in terms of special functions:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos (x t) t}{1+t} d t=\operatorname{Ci}(x) \cos (x)-\operatorname{Ci}(2 x) \cos (x)+\operatorname{Si}(x) \sin (x)+\left(\frac{1}{x}-\operatorname{Si}(2 x)\right) \sin (x).$$

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I will go back to check my notes because I did not realize that I could not depend on x.
And I will see how those steps are to solve the result that it has provided me.

Comment: I must use "Dominated convergence theorem", right?

Comment: @davidhernandez sounds right, yes

Comment: I already know how to solve it using Leibniz's integral rule, but I don't know how to apply it with Lebuesgue. There is a difference? Excuse me and thank you

Comment: If you can prove that you can apply Leibniz integral rule then you're fine